# JQuery Tab UI Integration

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tabs

I am implementing tabs for a page that is too long.  My original page before the tabs is here:

[http://199.119.123.133/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor_license_bond_tabs.htm]

My page after implementing the tabs is here:
[http://199.119.123.133/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor_license_bond_tabs.htm]

My FAQs and Videos are no longer showing in the tab version.  I believe this has to do with a CSS or JQuery issue, but after troubleshooting all afternoon, I'm stuck.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: The links are the same.

Comment: Can you tell which tries have you already made?

Comment: Whoops!  I posted the same link twice.  The original page can be found here: http://199.119.123.133/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor_license_bond.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is a stylesheet named settings.css which has a rule for your tabs that is hiding your lists too

```
.flat-tabs-left ul li {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
opacity: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 30px 25px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you comment (with a browser inspector) the opacity rule, and the padding you can see your lists appear, even though they are totally messed up. So it's a problem caused by the stylesheet that is styling your tabs. I guess it is a plugin or something.

You can try to use either bootstrap tabs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs or jquery tabs https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks Sissy!  Your suggestion worked to show my list of FAQs and Videos.  However, it also broke the functionality of the tabs, as clicking from tab to tab continues to display the previous tab below the border.  Thank you for the advice though, it is helping me find some direction!

Comment: yea i told you, it was not a complete solution but the place where to look to solve your issues. Glad it helped.  ;)